# A conjecture on a product of a positive-definite matrix and a vector

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

let $A$, $B$ positive-definite matrices,  and $v$ a vector. $A,B$ don't necessarily commute. Let $w:=(A+B)^{-1}Av$. Is it always the case that $|w_i| \le |v_i|$?

Answer (score 2):

No. When
$$
A=\pmatrix{2&-1\\ -1&1},\ B=\pmatrix{1&-2\\ -2&5},
$$
\begin{aligned}
(A+B)^{-1}A
&=(I+A^{-1}B)^{-1}\\
&=\left[I+\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&2}\pmatrix{1&-2\\ -2&5}\right]^{-1}\\
&=\pmatrix{0&3\\ -3&9}^{-1}\\
&=\pmatrix{1&-\tfrac13\\ \tfrac13&0}.
\end{aligned}
Therefore the Euclidean norm of the first column of $(A+B)^{-1}A$ is greater than $1$.